# Get indexOf char inside a string javascript

Tags: javascript, string, indexof

How can I check the index of a char within a string?

```
var str = 'alabama';
alert(str.indexOf('a'));
```

The "indexOf" method seems to work only at the first occurrence of the char.
Any ideas?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Find all occurrences of 'a'? Count how many 'a's?

Comment: I´m trying to get the indexes of the 'a's. In fact, I need to learn the process so I can use it to identify the position of the char and wrap it with a div.

Comment: If you have to wrap it with a div why don't you use `str.replace(/a/g, "<div>a</div>");` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write your own function:

```
function charIndexes(string, char) {
    var i, j, indexes = []; for(i=0,j=string.length;i<j;++i) {
        if(string.charAt(i) === char) {
            indexes.push(i);
        }
    }

    return indexes;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

To find subsequent occurrences, you need to supply the second parameter to `.indexOf`, repeatedly starting from one higher than the last occurrence found.

```
String.prototype.allIndexesOf = function(c, n) {
    var indexes = [];
    n = n || 0;
    while ((n = this.indexOf(c, n)) >= 0) {
        indexes.push(n++);
    }
    return indexes;
}
```

Test:

```
> "alabama".allIndexesOf("a")
[0, 2, 4, 6]
```

**EDIT** function updated to allow specification of a `fromIndex`, per `String.indexOf`.

Comment: yeah, there's a bad performance overhead adding to the prototype of built-in types in Chrome - http://jsperf.com/indexofso/2

Comment: Note also that this version preserves the semantics of `String.indexOf()` - the search string doesn't have to be a single character.

Comment: that's true, but the question was just about chars. So charAt will be ok, too.

Comment: Thx, this will do just fine. o/
But I´ll use Bennika´s because I felt a little slowdown in the page using yours (I´m doing this search in a blog post. So its a really huge string).

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = 'alabama',i=0, ci=[];

while((i=str.indexOf('a',i))!=-1)  ci.push(i++);

alert(ci.join(', '));
```